# Disable ctrl c and ctrl z while a script is running

Tags: shell-script, terminal, signals

I have a script that takes about 45 seconds to run.  How can I disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> while a script is running?

Answer (score 10):

Although you could disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> by disabling those terminal settings or setting the terminal to raw more or other solutions, you are usually much better off leaving them enabled and reacting to the resulting *signals* instead. You can install handlers for the signals and let the handlers do nothing.

The way to install handlers depends on the programming language you are using. You haven't said what you are using but here are a few examples:

Shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

trap '' INT TSTP
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

Comment: I am using #!/bin/bash

Comment: I was hoping to put some commands inside the script so it can not be interrupted while it is running.

Comment: @tester787 yes, that is exactly what I suggest that you do!

Comment: Edited to remove PEBKAC...  ;-)